# sql : Select value based on values from other columns

Tags: sql

I have a column for price. I need to select the price based on another column called status. If status is p then select that price first else select price from other status h. I need to make sure that query selects the price if status is p first when both status P & h are available.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added sample data but not sure why its displaying like that .. I copied from excel. but there are 3 columns.. price status and product and data is 23, p.,1

Comment: We would need your data to create the query, but this should just be something you can test yourself. It appears your query is basically written in the statement above. You should just create a test record that has a status for P & h and then see which one it pulls.

Comment: Are you working in Excel or Access?. The image looks like Excel, but there is no tag?

Comment: no but I was trying to put sample data here so that easy to understand for whoever is helping..I am working on sql developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rank` function (if your DBMS supports), which will group the rows based on product and rank the sub group rows based on status. then you can apply where clause to select first rank rows from each sub-group. the query will look like below for MS sql-server.

```
select price
, [status]
, product
from
    (select price
    , [status]
    , product
    , RANK() over (PARTITION BY product 
                   order by case 
                                when [status]='p' then 1 
                                else 0 
                            end desc
                   ) as rnk
    from @tableA) Q
where rnk =1
```

**Sample Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]